# Creating an instance of a nested Java class in ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion

I’m trying to create an instance of: [java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html) in ColdFusion.

Point2D.Double is a nested class inside of the abstract class Point2D.  I have tried to instantiate the class using:

```
<cfset PointClass = createObject("java", "java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double")>
```

This fails because ColdFusion cannot find the class.

And `<cfset PointClass = createObject("java", "java.awt.geom.Point2D")>` which does not work because Point2D is an abstract class and there is not a public constructor on which you can call `PointClass.init(x,y)`.

Right now, I’ve resorted to making my own Point class that wraps the Point2D.Double class so that I can instantiate it in ColdFusion.  I don’t think this is ideal and am looking for ideas about how to directly create a Point2D.Double class in ColdFusion.

I'm also using ColdFusion 8.

Comment: Your question is garbled. Please format the missing parts as code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try with:

```
<cfset PointClass = createObject("java", "java.awt.geom.Point2D$Double")>
```

For nested classes, use `$`

Comment: Kudos. Shame that this seems to be completely undocumented.